# Can glusterfs events APIs be used to warn of fs file changes?

Tags: glusterfs

My team is about to install glusterfd on our server infrastructure. I need to monitor when a file is added or deleted from the fs and call a url with the file name when this happens.

Can this be done with glusterfs's event apis or I will have to rely on good ol' cron to do this ?

I have thoroughly read all events and could only find events related to system like adding or removing a volume, brick or client connect/disconnect. Does it have any events for files also ?

Is there any apis documentation besides [this](https://docs.gluster.org/en/main/Administrator-Guide/Events-APIs/) and [this](https://docs.gluster.org/en/v3/Administrator%20Guide/Events%20APIs/) ?